# Recursive Stored Procedures USE

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I just want to know the scenario where I can use the stored procedure recursively.
Please give me a better Example.

Comment: Start here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: could not understand your question, add some script and why you want to use it recursively, or a whileloop to replace or script within proc and sample output

Comment: Create Proc AskBroadQuestion(@QNumber int) as exec dbo.AskBroadquestion(@QNumber + 1) go; exec AskBroadQuestion(1)

Comment: A better example than what? Stored procedures that need to work recursively is actually a very bad example of how to handle data.

Comment: An effective IT person should know [how to ask smart questions](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#stackoverflow) - especially with years of experience.

Answer (score 1):

Maximum stored procedure, function, trigger, or view nesting level exceeded (limit 32).

```
CREATE PROC dbo.Prc1 (@a int)
AS
    SELECT @a += 1;
    SELECT @a
    IF @a < 30
        EXEC dbo.Prc1 @a
GO

EXEC dbo.Prc1 @a = 0
```

May be enough use cte recirsion https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql